# Enable Protected content in Chromium on Raspbian

Tags: debian, raspbian, chrome

I can't seem to figure out how to enable protected content in Chromium, even though the option is enabled in settings.

URL I try to get working: https://open.spotify.com/browse

What I have tried:

1. change of userAgent
2. change of userAgent + using widevine library
       from a Chromebook image ([link](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/tutorial-chromium-netflix-and-other-drm-video-websites/7185))

After executing option 2 with the below userAgent, the website does not refer me to their "this browser does not work, try our app" page. Instead, it presents an error: "Spotify won't work if you block protected content, have an incompatible browser, or are using incognito browsing mode"

Chromium version 72.0.3626.121

Comment: Welcome to the world of DRM. I have the same issue and the solution that is working for me is using Firefox for Spotify ... On mobile I have the same when using IceCat.

Comment: I tried Firefox ESR, which has the same problem. However, I did not dive deep there yet. Did you have to undertake certain steps to get it working on Firefox?

Comment: It needs the checkbox `Play DRM-controlled content` in General Preferences (about:preferences#general) to be activated. I think this was the default, but not sure.

Comment: Which exact version of Firefox do you use? I can't seem to find this option anywhere.

Comment: @ThijmenDam In the navigation bar at the top of Firefox if you put in `about:preferences#general` about half way down that page should be a check box for `Play DRM-controlled content`. Support for online DRM content has been in Firefox since version 38 from what I can find online.

Comment: I have 69.02 but I remember it being there for long time already...

Comment: I looked at `about:preferences#general` as well als every other possible setting, but I was unfortunately not able to find it. Will look into it!

Comment: Firefox ESR does not support this setting. Managed to find a solution for Chromium however, please refer to my answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOLUTION

What a mess this DRM situation is. A lot of outdated info on the internet, but I managed to find a solution: https://blog.vpetkov.net/2019/07/12/netflix-and-spotify-on-a-raspberry-pi-4-with-latest-default-chromium/

```
cd /usr/lib/chromium-browser
wget http://blog.vpetkov.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/libwidevinecdm.so_.zip
unzip libwidevinecdm.so_.zip && chmod 755 libwidevinecdm.so
```

In my case, replacing the libwidevine was sufficient. I did not have to alter my user agent.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using **Chromium Snap**, then replacing **`cd /usr/lib/chromium-browser`** with **`~/snap/chromium/current/.local/lib/`** might help.

In my case, my chromium version didn't have lib folder so I just created one.

`cd ~/snap/chromium/current/.local/lib/` 
`wget http://blog.vpetkov.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/libwidevinecdm.so_.zip` 
`unzip libwidevinecdm.so_.zip && chmod 755 libwidevinecdm.so`

(in case you don't have a **lib** folder)
`mkdir ~/snap/chromium/current/.local/lib/` **(optional)**